# "NOAUTH Authentication required" Gitlab error with Azure cache for Redis

Tags: azure, redis, gitlab

I have created an Azure cache for Redis and I am trying to use it as external redis for Gitlab.

My `gitlab.rb` is this:

```rb
#external_url "https://ci.example.com"

nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/ci.example.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/ci.example.com.key"

### The duration in seconds to keep backups before they are allowed to be deleted
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800

### External postgres settings
postgresql['enable'] = false
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = "unicode"
gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "cisomething"
# username string for AWS
# gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
# username string for Azure
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab@ci-something.postgres.database.azure.com"
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "really long password"
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "ci-something.postgres.database.azure.com"
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
gitlab_rails['auto_migrate'] = false

### External redis settings
redis['enable'] = false
gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = "ci.redis.cache.windows.net"
gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = 6379
gitlab_rails['redis_password'] = "azure-redis-primary-access-key"

### Whitelist VPC cidr for access to health checks
gitlab_rails['monitoring_whitelist'] = ['XX.XXX.X.X/24']

### Default Theme
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_theme'] = 2

### Enable or disable automatic database migrations
gitlab_rails['auto_migrate'] = false

### GitLab email server settings
... other settings here
```

I can connect to Redis with `redis-cli`

`redis-cli -h ci.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6379 -a azure-redis-primary-access-key`

and execute commands.

When I execute `gitlab-ctl tail` I see this error:

```sh
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{"error":"keywatcher: pubsub receive: NOAUTH Authentication required.","level":"error","msg":"unknown error","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"address":"ci.redis.cache.windows.net","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","scheme":"redis","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"error":"keywatcher: pubsub receive: NOAUTH Authentication required.","level":"error","msg":"unknown error","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"address":"ci.redis.cache.windows.net","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","scheme":"redis","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"error":"keywatcher: pubsub receive: NOAUTH Authentication required.","level":"error","msg":"unknown error","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"address":"ci.redis.cache.windows.net","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","scheme":"redis","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"error":"keywatcher: pubsub receive: NOAUTH Authentication required.","level":"error","msg":"unknown error","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
{"address":"ci.redis.cache.windows.net","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","scheme":"redis","time":"2020-02-21T10:26:08Z"}
```

I searched the internet but I cannot find something to resolve this.

```
System information
System:     Ubuntu 16.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.6.5p114
Gem Version:    2.7.10
Bundler Version:1.17.3
Rake Version:   12.3.3
Redis Version:  5.0.7
Git Version:    2.24.1
Sidekiq Version:5.2.7

GitLab information
Version:    12.7.6
Revision:   61654d25b20
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 9.5.20,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out.
For future reference here it goes.

`gitlab.rb`

```rb
### External redis settings
redis['enable'] = false
gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = "ci.redis.cache.windows.net"
gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = 6380
gitlab_rails['redis_password'] = "azure-primary-access-key"
gitlab_rails['redis_ssl'] = true
```

Azure Cache for Redis configuration [Azure portal]

[image]

Final note:
When deploying the Gitlab VM, check the logs with `gitlab-ctl tail`. If you see the redis default port to be `6379` means that Sidekiq has old configuration, which as I observed is not updated with `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Delete the VM and redeploy it.